# Keep line that contains X within the first two fields

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a .txt converted from .csv that looks like this

```
Smith","example","example","example","example"
example","Smith","example","example","example"
example","Smith","example","Smith","example"
example","example","example","Smith","example"
John","example","example","example","example"
example","example","example","John","example"
```

I want to only keep lines that contain the words `Smith` or `John` but they have to be within the first two fields

Output should be:

```
Smith","example","example","example","example"
example","Smith","example","example","example"
example","Smith","example","Smith","example"
John","example","example","example","example"
```

The first two fields might not exactly be `John` or `Smith`, they could be `Johnson` for example, I would still like to keep that.

If the first two fields don't contain either John or Smith then that line should be removed. If the first or second fields contain them the line should be kept no matter what (if the whole line had "John" for example)

Comment: No leading quote?  That seems to me a somewhat ill-formed CSV, is it really correct?

Comment: Yes (12 chara limit)

Comment: May the fields contain comas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
grep -E '^([^,]*,")?(Smith|John)'  <infile
```

...will print...

```
Smith","example","example","example","example"
example","Smith","example","example","example"
example","Smith","example","Smith","example"
John","example","example","example","example"
```

Comment: grep -E '^([^,]+,")?(Smith|John)"'  <newname.txt > new.txt - Created an empty file. I forgot to mention sorry that the line might not exactly be "Smith" it could be Smithy, just contain "Smith"

Comment: @Teddy291 - Ok, so are you not trying definitely to match the whole field? I stuck that last quote in specifically to guard against Smithy - I never liked that guy.

Comment: Exactly, there could be "Smithy", "Johnson", "Smithy Sucks" - I would like to keep them all :)

Comment: @Teddy291 - try it without the trailing quote then - it will only match the head of each field - anything may follow. And tell Smithy I want my $20.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
< inputfile awk -F, '$1$2~/Smith|John/'
```

Output:

```bsh
~/tmp$ cat inputfile
Smith","example","example","example","example"
example","Smith","example","example","example"
example","Smith","example","Smith","example"
example","example","example","Smith","example"
John","example","example","example","example"
example","example","example","John","example"
~/tmp$ < inputfile awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} $1~/Smith|John/||$2~/Smith|John/'
Smith","example","example","example","example"
example","Smith","example","example","example"
example","Smith","example","Smith","example"
John","example","example","example","example"
```

Comment: I would use `awk -F,` rather than `awk 'BEGIN { FS=","} `.

Comment: If you use `FS="\",\""` (or `-F'","'`) it will also handle possible commas within the quoted fields, I think?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, it does, thanks for the input

Comment: @Archemar I'm not sure. I've always done it like that because i use `gawk`, so I *think* that's the most compatible way as long as I don't use very specific features, because there's no risk to break options. However it might be that `-F` is supported an almost all versions, I've never checked. If that's the case well, I'd fancy it more either.

Comment: [Yes, `-F` is POSIX.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html). You also don't need to escape the `"`, if you want to use `FS`, you could do `BEGIN{FS=","}`. Alternatively, in addition to `-F,`, you can also do `awk -vFS=","`. Finally, you could condense the whole thing to `awk -F, '$1$2~/Smith|John/'`.

Comment: @terdon Yes, in fact the previous version didn't have the qoutes escaped, I tried steeldriver's suggestion to not split records containing `,`, however I was a bit of a fool since I probably tested on a record with a second field containing `"Smith,otherstuff"`, which matches anyway. Thanks for the POSIX notice and for the shortened syntax, I didn't know you could shorten expressions that way.